# Кодировка в консоли Visual Studio, знаки вопроса вместо русских букв

Tags: c#, консоль

[image: Консоль с вопросами]

Visual studio 2019, professional Кодировка сломана, в консоли Visual Studio знаки вопроса вместо русских букв. Нашёл вроде статью как решить проблему, https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/907291/question-marks-unexpectedly-appear-instead-of-localized-characters-whe , но не смог на сайте майкрософт найти Apploc.msi , с другого сайта качал, ошибка во время установки. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Язык C#, .NET Framework (4.7.5 кажется)

Comment: У C# по умолчанию нет проблем с кодировкой. Покажи код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022114/decoding-a-string-c-sharp

Comment: Сейчас запустил код на другом компе, тут с кодировкой всё хорошо.  Этот же код работает правильно

Comment: Кстати, покажи параметры консоли, возможно там какой-то шрифт неудачный.

Answer (score 1):

Я сам столкнулся с этой проблемой, искал решение пипец как долго. Тебе надо зайти в Region cправа надпись "additional date, time..." как на скрине, только у  меня все на инглише у тебя все должно быть всё по-русски. Потом "administrative"/ "change system locate", и смени на русский. Короче, просто следуй скринам
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это для C#? Он же юникодный.

Comment: для меня сработало

Answer (score 0):

Я приведу пример для Win10, для других систем аналогично, только названия пунктов будут другие.

Пуск/Параметры/Время и язык(распознавание голоса, регион, дата)/Регион/Дополнительные параметры даты, времени, региона/Региональные стандарты/Дополнительно/Текущий язык программ, не поддерживающий Юникод - Изменить язык системы

И тут Английский(США) поменять на Русский(Россия)
Экспериментальную галочку напротив Юникода ставить не нужно. У меня были проблемы связанные как раз с этой галочкой. Нужно было найти ее и отключить.

Если не поможет, нашел [вариант с редактированием реестра](https://ixnfo.com/znaki-voprosa-vmesto-russkih-bukv-reshenie-problemyi-s-kodirovkoy-windows.html), но у меня до этого не дошло.

Из проблем остались вопросики там где должны выводиться денежные знаки для текущего региона, пока не победил. Код на C# для проверки

Console.WriteLine("C format: {0:C}", 2.50);     // Валюта

[Картинка что где жать](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjFwN.png)

Comment: Так программы на шарпе вполне юникодные. У него же не плюсы в вопросе. Я бы скорее шрифт консоли порверял.

Answer (score -1):

Win 10
У меня тоже были знаки вопроса в консоли. Мне как раз помогло переключение даного параметра на Английский(США)

Пуск/Параметры/Время и язык(распознавание голоса, регион, дата)/Регион/Дополнительные параметры даты, времени, региона/Региональные стандарты/Дополнительно/Текущий язык программ, не поддерживающий Юникод - Изменить язык системы(с русского на английский)

И вместо абракадабры появились нормальные слова =)

Comment: чем именно ваш ответ отличается от других ответов?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: aleksandr barakin, тем что я написал какие действия мне помогли решить даную проблему. В предыдущем комментарии к примеру советуют переключить на русский, а я на английский